# Printing the 2nd values in 2d Array

Tags: java, 2d

What change do I need to make in the following code

```
public void demo() {
    int[][] num = {{0, 30}, {5, 10}, {15, 20}};

    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
     // System.out.println(num[i][0]); 
        for(int j = 0; j < num[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(num[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So that I can get 30,10,20 ?
I want to find 0,5,15 which `num[i][0]` is doing. I am not sure what change to make just to get the 30,10,20

I do not want to use `num[i][j]` to get the pair values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void demo() {
    int[][] num = {{0, 30}, {5, 10}, {15, 20}};

    for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++){
       System.out.println(num[i][1]); 
    }
}
```